# Backend Error and Retrieving activity limitation

Tags: api, google-plus

When ever i try to retrieve the google plus post of a particular user,
i get the following message

{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "buzz", "reason": "backendError", "message":    "Backend Error" } ], "code": 503, "message": "Backend Error" } }

The query fails only for few peoples (consistently) but still it's
important for me, below is the query which i am using.

https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/"user_id"/activities/public?
maxResults=100&key="Api_key"

And when ever i try to retrieve the posts of a user for whom the above
query works perfectly, i am only able to retrieve last 250 posts.

Is there a way to retrieve all the post which they have posted so far?

Comment: Are you trying this from a web browser? I'm having the same problem but for some reason, the query works with `curl` but not from `jQuery.ajax` :-/

Comment: Nevermind my issue. I was treating profile IDs as Numbers in JavaScript and I was losing precision. Always use Strings :-)

Comment: I don't get the above error message while retrieving the post through php client library but i am only able to retrieve 200 posts :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this issue as well, and the problem I was running into was that I was storing profile IDs in JavaScript as `Number` values, which was chopping off precision. So `113735310430199015092` was being rounded to `113735310430199020000`. The lesson there is to always store Google+ profile IDs as `String` values in JavaScript.

**So the 'backendError' was basically being thrown due to an invalid or otherwise inaccessible profile ID.**

Now, I'm not sure if that's the exact issue you're running into, since 'backendError' is fairly generic, and a 5xx HTTP code says nothing about the validity of your response, but it's something to watch out for. I'm hoping in the future the API will return a more useful 4xx status code for these error cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related bug which is being tracked here: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=7